# What is the cardinality of the relative complement of two infinite sets that have the same cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets where $card(A) = card(B)$, what is  $card(A\setminus B)$, where $A\setminus B$ denotes relative complement?

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I added some TeX and improved the notation a little. Feel free to rollback if it's not ok.

Comment: It could be a whole lot of things.

Answer (score 3):

There is not enough information. If $A=B=\mathbb{N}$ then $A\setminus B=\emptyset$ and so $card(A\setminus B)=0$. If $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\{n\in A\mid n\geq 0\}$ then $A\setminus B=\{n\in A\mid n\leq -1\}$ and so $card(A\setminus B)=\aleph_0$. What we can say is that $card(A\setminus B)$ is no greater than $card(A)$, but not much more without more information.

Comment: (Assuming AC) We can say that the possible cardinalities are precisely those no greater than $\mathrm{card}(A)$.

Comment: Thank you this is very good.   If A = {0, 1,2,..} = whole numbers and B ={2, 3, 4, ...}, hence, CARD(B) = Alpha null, how would one then calculate the A\B and CARD(A\B)?

Comment: @tf177: For the concrete example you just gave, reviewing the definition of $A\setminus B$ should allow you determine what numbers are in that set.  Then you will see how many numbers are in the set.

Comment: So if set A = {0, 1, 2, 3,...} and B = (2, 4, 6,...}, then B/A = {0, 1, 3,...} = {non-negative odd number}.  CARD(B\A) = Alepha null.

Comment: What texts in set theory can I study to learn more about the type of question I posed earlier?